# How to calculate an orthogonal plane from a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a position in space called X1. X1 has a velocity called V1. I need to construct an orthogonal plane perpendicular to the velocity vector. The origin of the plane is X1.

I need to turn the two edges from the plane into two vectors, E1 and E2. The edges connect at the origin. So the three vectors form an axis

Comment: Frankly, this makes no sense to me.  A [I]position[/I] in space does not have a velocity!  Nor does a plane have "edges".  A plane in $R^3$ can be written "ax+ by+ cz= P".  And it will be orthogonal to vector V1 if and only if the dot product of V1 with the vector <a, b, c>.

Comment: Is it possible to rephrase your question? Maybe you want the equation of a plane when you know a normal vector to it and the coordinates of a point on it?

Comment: Imagine the position is a particle, and it has a velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve already got a normal to the plane—the velocity vector—and a point on it—the position—so you can immediately write down an equation for the plane: $\mathbf v_1\cdot(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_1)=0$. If you’re looking for a pair of vectors that span the plane, just find a basis for the orthogonal complement of $\mathbf v_1$. Since you appear to be working in $\mathbb R^3$, you can do this easily with a cross product. Suppose $\mathbf v=(v_x,v_y,v_z)$. For $\mathbf e_1$ you can take one of $(v_y,-v_x,0)$, $(-v_z,0,v_x)$, $(0,v_z,-v_y)$ or any number of other easily computed vectors. Then, set $\mathbf e_2=\mathbf e_1\times\mathbf v_1$. Normalize these vectors if you need unit vectors.

Comment: This looks right, let me test it